# Bastion MFA enabled account Login Failure

Tags: azure, azure-bastion

I am trying to use bastion which works fine with account without mfa but get login failed when using mfa account and get below in audit log

OperationName
Microsoft.Network/BastionHost/disconnect
Message
Login Failed

Is this known issue where it cannot be used with MFA?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the [MS DOC :](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/security/benchmark/azure/baselines/bastion-security-baseline#im-1-standardize-azure-active-directory-as-the-central-identity-and-authentication-system)

> Connecting to virtual machines using Azure Bastion relies on either an
> SSH key or username/password, and currently does not support the use
> of Azure AD credentials.

For more information please refer this Microsoft Documentation - [Login to Windows virtual machine in Azure using Azure Active Directory authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/devices/howto-vm-sign-in-azure-ad-windows) .

Comment: I am not clear about the statement, we are running Azure AD Domain Services and the VM trying to connect is domain joined using JsonADDomainExtension. When using bastion to get to the VM with domain account user1@domain.com works fine but when MFA enabled user1@domain.com gives Login Failed (so am using username/password) in both the cases.

Comment: Hello @user14173614 , As per MS DOC you can not login with MFA enabled user into your VM, You have to disable the MFA of the user to log-in to VM. Please refer this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/devices/howto-vm-sign-in-azure-ad-windows#mfa-sign-in-method-required under MFA-sign-in-method required .

Comment: Any update ? If the above information resolve your issue, Could you please mark it as answer to help other community members for similar issue. Thanks:)

Comment: The document talks about Azure Windows VM, I am trying to log on to WindowsVM to Azure Active Directory Domain Services using JsonADDomainExtension so should not be applicable to our scenario? I have not found any reference around WindowsVM to Azure Active Directory Domain Services

Comment: Could you please refer this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-domain-services/join-windows-vm .

Comment: The above doc. explain howto use domain services with our windows vm, Let me know if this helps .I will update it on my answers . Thanks:)

Comment: Yes but the bastion does not work if I have MFA enabled on my account.

Comment: We can not use BASTION with MFA  enabled . We need to use BASTION to connect with our windows/azure VM . For more information please refer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bastion/tutorial-create-host-portal & Article https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/what-is-azure-bastion-and-how-to-enable-azure-bastion-on-a-vm/